# Указатели: что хранится в переменной?

Tags: указатели, c++

Допустим, есть `const char *v = "name"`;
что тогда будет хранится в переменной v? строка?
и зачем сие используется в языке?

Comment: @serg, на самом деле в переменной `v` будет число. 

Оно будет интерпретируется аппаратурой компьютера как адрес в виртуальной памяти текущего процесса.

Посмотреть на него (и узнать размер переменной в байтах) можно так

    printf ("v content: %p   v size %ld bytes\n", v, (long)sizeof(v));

а вот по этому адресу в памяти будут байты

    name

(с двоичным нулем в конце)


--

Откуда это число появляется в `v` при такой записи на С/С++?  

Несколько упрощенный ответ -- *совместными действиями* сначала компилятора, а потом операционной системы (если считать линкер компонентом ОС).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В v будет хранится указатель на ячейку памяти, где лежит символ 'n', первый символ этой строки.
Строковые функции, когда им передают указатель типа char, предполагают, что этот указатель указывает на первый символ строки, которая обязательно оканчивается нулем (нуль-символом, зеро-терминатором, условно обозначается - '\0').

А сие используется в языке, потому как чистого строкового типа в С нет. Собственно, нет никакой разницы (кроме соглашения о дополнительном нуль-символе в конце и типов данных) между массивом целых чисел и массивом символов (строкой).
В C++ есть класс, который является оберткой над такими "сырыми" строками (или С-строками), про который можно сказать - он хранит строку. Это тип std::string.

Comment: и еще такой вопрос, если я напишу char con[]="string", то у меня память и под строковый литерал и под массив выделится?

Comment: @serg: Строковый литерал и есть массив (символов).

Comment: @VladD ну тогда память под два массива или под один?

Comment: @serg Это, по сути, константа, под нее память выделится лишь раз. А указатель указывает на единожды выделенную память. Если вы хотите выделять память в процессе работы программы, вам потребуется изменять строку, то необходимо в явном виде: 1) выделить память подходящего размера 2) скопировать значения 3)работать с этой памятью 4)освободить память после использования

Comment: @serg: Эээ... А где вы видите тут _два_ массива?

Comment: @serg, при записи

    char con[] = "string";

выделится 7 байт памяти (массив), которые *будут проинициализированы* символами 's' 't' 'r' 'i' 'n' 'g' '\0'.